# jQuery UI Sortable for a whole div when clicked on a children element

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'd like to move around a list item with the sortable jQuery UI helper. I want to use some sort of handle : being able to move the whole div but only when using that handle. I don't want the div to move when clicking elsewhere than the handle.

Any idea how to do that ? I searched the documentation and didn't find anything. My only current idea would be to set some sort of function that enables the sortable state when I press the handle and disable it when I release the mouse but it feels sloppy.

Comment: can you set it up in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wt4z4/
Here it is. I'd like to be able to move the list items only when clicking on 'H'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `handle` option:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $('#sortable_list').sortable({axis: 'y', handle: '.handle'});
    }
);​
```